# Can $0$ be added to any equation without changing the outcome?

Tags: arithmetic, binary-operations

I was thinking about adding $0$ to an equation, e.g.:

A very simple one:
$$2x + 2 = 10\\  
2x = 8  \\
x = 4  .$$

If you add "$+ 0$" to any side it does not change the outcome. 
$2x + 2 + 0 = 10  \implies x$ is still $4$.

Are there any equations, formulae or mathematical constructs where adding "$0$"  does change the outcome?

Comment: In any situation where this isn't true, either the quantity denoted $0$ doesn't deserve to be called zero, or the notion we're calling 'addition' doesn't deserve to be called addition.

Comment: If we are dealing with real numbers and the typical definitions of addition... you can add zero to any equation and it will not change it.

Comment: @Travis, so if I understand you correctly: With our normal definitions of `+` and `0`, this can never happen? I hoped there were some obscure situation where adding 0 would change the outcome :( - Math, I am disappointed!

Comment: I avoided making a precise statement because the question itself isn't precise, namely, it doesn't specify what $0$ are "adding" are. What I'm saying is that if we denote some notions by $+$ and $0$ but the identity $A + 0 = A$ or a suitable analogue does not hold, then that notation is probably misleading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have an equation, there are only two (types of) things you're allowed to to. 1: make a change to one side that does not change the value of that side. 2: do the same thing to both sides.

Adding $0$ to an expression does not change its value, and as such, you are allowed to do it to one side of an equation and not the other. Most of the time adding $0$ is just a gimmick, but some times it can be very valuable. Particularily in the form of "Add something, then subtract the same ting". One example I like is when proving the formula for the derivative of a product of two functions. There you have the following transition: (note, these are not *equations*, trying to solve for an unknown, but *equalities*, finding as simlpe as possible an expression for some predetermined value)
$$
\frac{f(x+h)\cdot g(x+h) - f(x) \cdot g(x)}{h} \\
= \frac{f(x+h)\cdot g(x+h) \color{red}{-f(x+h)\cdot g(x) + f(x+h) \cdot g(x)} - f(x)\cdot g(x)}{h} \\
= \frac{f(x+h)\cdot\big[g(x + h) - g(x)\big] + g(x)\big[f(x + h) - f(x)\big]}{h}
$$
where the fact that we add $-f(x+h)\cdot g(x) + f(x+h)\cdot g(x)$, which is zero, allows us to factor the numerator into something we can handle later on.

So, adding $0$ does not change the value of any expression, and thus is something you're allowed to do at any time. However, some times it can greatly affect the *look* of an expression, allowing for algebraic manipulations that were unavailable before.

Answer (score 1):

This is true by definition of the number $0$. It is defined as **the** number such that $x+0=x$.